# How to edit nested reactive form with validation?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular2-forms

I am retrieving the data from service which has a data format in array. Now how do i bind data in the nesting form if i have array of n number of data? Form will already filled up with this data and the validation fields are also applied in it.

This is my **parent component html** code.

```
<form [formGroup]="secondForm" (ngSubmit)="onSecondSubmit()" *ngIf="EnableSecond" [hidden]="!myForm.valid">

            <div formArrayName="items">

                <div *ngFor="let address of secondForm.get('items')['controls']; let i=index">


                    <div>
                        <label>Email Template - {{i + 1}}</label>
                        <span *ngIf="secondForm.controls.items.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeAddress(i)"> Remove
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <editworkflow [groups]="secondForm.controls.items.controls[i]"></editworkflow>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a (click)="addAddress()">
                Create More Email Template
            </a>
            <div>
                <div>

                    <button nbButton type="submit" [disabled]="!secondForm.valid">Confirm</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is the **parent component typescript** file.

```
ngOnint(){
this.usermodel.items =   this.items /*my array of object which i am getting 
from services*/ 
this.secondForm = this._fb.group({
        items: this._fb.array([
            this.initAddress(),
        ])
    });
}
initAddress() {
    return this._fb.group({
        EmailType: [this.usermodel.items.name, Validators.required],
        name: [this.usermodel.items.name, Validators.required],
        subject: [this.usermodel.items.template.subject, Validators.required],
        'from': [this.usermodel.items.template.from, [Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator]],
        'body': [this.usermodel.items.template.body, [Validators.required]],
        'active': [],
        'confidential': [],
        'numberOfDaysToWait': ['', Validators.required],
        'sequentialOrder': ['', Validators.required]
    });

}

addAddress() {
    // add address to the list

    const control = <FormArray>this.secondForm.controls['items'];
    control.push(this.initAddress());
}

removeAddress(i: number) {
    // remove address from the list
    const control = <FormArray>this.secondForm.controls['items'];
    control.removeAt(i);
}
```

My array of object will look like this.

```
   "items": [
    {
      "template": {
        "name": "Series 1 email",
        "from": "TEAMGMG",
        "subject": "GROUP2 - SERIES1 - EMAIL",
        "body": "<html><body><strong>My test email</strong></body></html>",
        "confidential": true,
        "active": true
      },
      "sequentialOrder": 1,
      "numberOfDaysToWait": 0,
      "name": "Test email sequence 1",
      "description": "Test email GROUP 2 sequence 1 - description"
    }, {
      "template": {
        "name": "Series 2 email",
        "from": "TEAMGMG",
        "subject": "GROUP2 - SERIES2 - EMAIL",
        "body": "<html><body><strong>My test email2</strong></body></html>",
        "confidential": true,
        "active": true
      },
      "sequentialOrder": 2,
      "numberOfDaysToWait": 10,
      "name": "Test email sequence 2",
      "description": "Test email sequence 2 - description"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: no. i am not getting the way to bind the elements or how do i pass my values in html ?

Comment: i am getting the data in this variable  which is array of objects this.userModel.items   . now how do i pass this model into ngfor loop . one loop is already for form control

Comment: Could you please explain further what your problem is? I dont quite understand. You are saying that "Form will already filled up with this data and the validation fields are also applied in it."

Comment: I don't see "userModels" in your code

Comment: this.usermodel.items contain the data which i am getting from services.which i have not included in question. but suppose this.usermodel.items contains a array of object. now i when i clicked on edit button the form will be already filled up with this values.

Comment: Please check the data format which i am getting through the services.(Edited Question)

Comment: I still don't understand. You use form arrays correctly, what is hindering you to add form elements inside the ngFor you correctly use with the controls of your form array?

Comment: with the controls i also wanted to loop my array of items which i am getting from services. because i want to edit those value also. so how do i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that received a "data" or null and return a FormGroup

```
  addAddress(data:any) {
    //if received a null, create a data with the necesary properties
    data=data||{template:{from:'',:'',name:'',subject:'',...},sequentialOrder:0,...}
    return this._fb.group({
        EmailType: [data.template.from, Validators.required],
        name: [data.template.name, Validators.required],
        subject: [data.template.subject, Validators.required],
        'from': [data.template.from, [Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator]],
        'body': [data.template.body, [Validators.required]],
        'active': [data.template.active],
        'confidential': [data.template.confidential],
        'numberOfDaysToWait': [data.numberOfDaysToWait, Validators.required],
        'sequentialOrder': [data.sequentialOrder, Validators.required]
    });
 }
```

So, you can add to your array with a

```
control.push(this.addAddress(null));
//or
control.push(this.addAddress(data));
```

You can use on ngOnInit

```
this.usermodel.items =   this.items
this.secondForm = this._fb.group({
        items: this._fb.array(items.map(data=>this.addAddress(data))
    });
}
```

The items.map, convert your array of items in an array of formGroup

Comment: the data which you have create. this data will be in this.usermodel.items. which i can access globally and check my addAddress() function i m already pushing the data .but how can i use this in a loop. suppose i will replace your data.template.from with my this.userModel.items.name. so will it solve the problem ?

Comment: and where do i call this addAddress() function ?

Comment: when you has your array of object you can do, e.g. const  control=<FormArray>this.secondForm.controls['items'];control=item.forEach(x=>control.push(this.addAddress(x))

Comment: check my edited question format . this is what you want me to do . but how to i pass this data in my child component.?

Comment: i want my form to be pre filled with this values.

Comment: I update my answer, but really you need put in the subscribe to the service